# Form not working on including Semantics UI CDNs

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui, cdn

I am trying to create a form where I am using fomantic UI but it's not working, the calendar and dropdowns are not responding on click, I've downloaded the semantic UI zip file and included them in my form page but it is not responding, what am I missing here, will deeply appreciate your help on this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Form</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../resources/assets/Semantic-UI-CSS-master/semantic.css">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Mitr:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../resources/css/biodata.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="ui blue inverted borderless menu">
         <a class="active item">
         Home
         </a>
         <div class="right menu">
            <a class="item">
            Login
            </a>
            <a class="item">
            Sign Up
            </a>
            <a class="item">
            Sign Out
            </a>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container centered" id="datacontainer">
         <form class="ui form" id="dataform">
            <div class="ui card">
               <div class="image" id="image-1">
                  <img src="C:\Users\ABC\Pictures\picture-1.jpg">
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
               <div class="inline fields">
                  <span class="indataform"> <label>First Name</label> </span>
                  <input class="forminclass" type="text" name="first-name" placeholder="First Name">
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
               <div class="inline fields">
                  <span class="indataform"> <label>Last Name</label> </span>
                  <input class="forminclass" type="text" name="last-name" placeholder="Last Name">
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
               <div class="inline fields">
                  <span class="indataform"> <label>Email</label></span>
                  <input class="forminclass" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
               <div class="inline fields">
                  <span class="indataform"> <label>Phone</label></span>
                  <input class="forminclass" type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone">
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
               <div class="inline fields">
                  <span class="indataform">   <label>Gender</label> </span>
                  <div class="ui selection dropdown">
                     <input class="forminclass" type="hidden" name="gender">
                     <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
                     <div class="default text">Gender</div>
                     <div class="menu">
                        <div class="item" data-value="1">Male</div>
                        <div class="item" data-value="0">Female</div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
               <div class="inline fields">
                  <span class="indataform"> <label>Date of Birth</label> </span>
                  <div class="ui calendar" id="example1">
                     <div class="ui input left icon">
                        <i class="calendar icon"></i>
                        <input id="dob"type="text">
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
               <div class="inline fields">
                  <span class="indataform">  <label>Text</label> </span>
                  <textarea id="areat" rows="2"></textarea>
               </div>
            </div>
            <button class="ui green button" id="edit" type="submit">Edit</button>
            <button class="ui flex primary button" id="save" type="submit">Save</button>
         </form>
      </div>
      <script
         src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"
         integrity="sha256-r/AaFHrszJtwpe+tHyNi/XCfMxYpbsRg2Uqn0x3s2zc="
         crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="../resources/assets/Semantic-UI-CSS-master/semantic.min.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Here's my HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Form</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../resources/assets/Semantic-UI-CSS-master/semantic.css">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Mitr:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../resources/css/biodata.css">
</head>
<body>

        <div class="ui blue inverted borderless menu">
          <a class="active item">
            Home
          </a>
           <div class="right menu">
            <a class="item">
            Login
          </a>
          <a class="item">
            Sign Up
          </a>
             <a class="item">
            Sign Out
          </a>
          </div>
        </div>



        <div class="container centered" id="datacontainer">
            <form class="ui form" id="dataform">

                <div class="ui card">
                   <div class="image" id="image-1">
                        <img src="C:\Users\ABC\Pictures\picture-1.jpg">
                    </div>
                </div>
                 <div class="field">
                    <div class="inline fields">
                       <span class="indataform"> <label>First Name</label> </span>
                        <input class="forminclass" type="text" name="first-name" placeholder="First Name">
                    </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="field">
                    <div class="inline fields">
                       <span class="indataform"> <label>Last Name</label> </span>
                        <input class="forminclass" type="text" name="last-name" placeholder="Last Name">
                   </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="field">
                        <div class="inline fields">
                           <span class="indataform"> <label>Email</label></span>
                            <input class="forminclass" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="field">
                        <div class="inline fields">
                        <span class="indataform"> <label>Phone</label></span>
                            <input class="forminclass" type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="field">
                    <div class="inline fields">
                   <span class="indataform">   <label>Gender</label> </span>
                          <div class="ui selection dropdown">
                              <input class="forminclass" type="hidden" name="gender">
                              <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
                              <div class="default text">Gender</div>
                              <div class="menu">
                                  <div class="item" data-value="1">Male</div>
                                  <div class="item" data-value="0">Female</div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <div class="inline fields">
                    <span class="indataform">   <label>Date of Birth</label> </span>
                        <div class="ui calendar" id="example1">
                            <div class="ui input left icon">
                              <i class="calendar icon"></i>
                              <input id="dob"type="text">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <div class="inline fields">
                  <span class="indataform">  <label>Text</label> </span>
                    <textarea id="areat" rows="2"></textarea>
                </div>
              </div>

                 <button class="ui green button" id="edit" type="submit">Edit</button>
                 <button class="ui flex primary button" id="save" type="submit">Save</button>

        </form>
        </div>


<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"
  integrity="sha256-r/AaFHrszJtwpe+tHyNi/XCfMxYpbsRg2Uqn0x3s2zc="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../resources/assets/Semantic-UI-CSS-master/semantic.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help. Placement of CSS and js files were incorrect.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Form</title>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.css">
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Mitr:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../resources/css/biodata.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="ui blue inverted borderless menu">
         <a class="active item">
         Home
         </a>
         <div class="right menu">
            <a class="item">
            Login
            </a>
            <a class="item">
            Sign Up
            </a>
            <a class="item">
            Sign Out
            </a>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container centered" id="datacontainer">
         <form class="ui form" id="dataform">
            <div class="ui card">
               <div class="image" id="image-1">
                  <img src="C:\Users\ABC\Pictures\picture-1.jpg">
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
               <div class="inline fields">
                  <span class="indataform"> <label>First Name</label> </span>
                  <input class="forminclass" type="text" name="first-name" placeholder="First Name">
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
               <div class="inline fields">
                  <span class="indataform"> <label>Last Name</label> </span>
                  <input class="forminclass" type="text" name="last-name" placeholder="Last Name">
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
               <div class="inline fields">
                  <span class="indataform"> <label>Email</label></span>
                  <input class="forminclass" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
               <div class="inline fields">
                  <span class="indataform"> <label>Phone</label></span>
                  <input class="forminclass" type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone">
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
               <div class="inline fields">
                  <span class="indataform">   <label>Gender</label> </span>
                  <div class="ui selection dropdown">
                     <input class="forminclass" type="hidden" name="gender">
                     <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
                     <div class="default text">Gender</div>
                     <div class="menu">
                        <div class="item" data-value="1">Male</div>
                        <div class="item" data-value="0">Female</div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
               <div class="inline fields">
                  <span class="indataform">   <label>Date of Birth</label> </span>
                  <div class="ui calendar" id="example1">
                     <div class="ui input left icon">
                        <i class="calendar icon"></i>
                        <input id="dob"type="text">
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
               <div class="inline fields">
                  <span class="indataform">  <label>Text</label> </span>
                  <textarea id="areat" rows="2"></textarea>
               </div>
            </div>
            <button class="ui green button" id="edit" type="submit">Edit</button>
            <button class="ui flex primary button" id="save" type="submit">Save</button>
         </form>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am simply reffering to installation steps given on Semantic UI website, https://semantic-ui.com/introduction/getting-started.html

Comment: Try to use cnd urls and put into head tag and then try.

Comment: Or if you are loading semantic js and CSS files from your local machine, then make sure that path is correct.